# how to operate the sovereign address's balance

Tags: xcm, account

If the "sovereign account" has some balance or vesting balance on a parachain, how to operate the sovereign address's balance?

Example:
para2000's sovereign account has 100Unit on para2001.
Can para2000 transfer 1Unit to another address on para2001?
Can para2000 send an XCM to para2001 to operate their sovereign account balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send an XCM message with root origin (use sudo or democracy).

The root origin of your chain is the sovereign account on other parachains in XCMP.

---

And this is how the attacker did to stole 11700 KSMs on Mangata.

Check:

https://blog.mangata.finance/blog/2022-10-08-council-incident-report/
https://mangatax.stg.subscan.io/council/0?tab=proposal